# Eclipse not working after deleting a version of java

Tags: java, eclipse

I found out I had the JRE and the JDK on 2 different folders, I then deleted the JRE. The JRE is still here in the JDK install.

I then searched a bit about the problem. I created the environment variable (I am on W10) `JAVA_PATH` with the good path but it still doesn't work.

A dialog box says (I can't copy paste all) :

```
JVM terminated
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe

(lots of things)
```

I don't know how to get it working.

Comment: Reinstall the JDK.  Don't delete the JRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling your JRE will solve the problem. If you want to get rid of some software always deinstall it if possible because you don't know where all of the files and settings were installed.

Answer (score 1):

you will need java, if you have a JDK the a JRE is included there by default...,  maybe you had 2 version of java and you still have a jdk, so lets say you deleted the jre, then you need to tell the eclipse IDE that it must use the version you have installed and where it can find it..

How:

like this...
[image]

but now, if you deleted ALL the java versions then you will need to install at least one...

Answer (score 0):

You should have defined your environment variable as `JAVA_HOME` and assign it your JDK's path. Then, add this variable to your `PATH` variable as `JAVA_HOME/bin`.